# Google Maps Not showing Navigation option

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have google maps in my android application. The problem is that after i have intialized a marker to a specific location, and when i try to click on that marker, the navigation option does not come instead, i get zoom view options. This happened when i imported my maps code from a perfectly working project(in this i was getting the navigation option). How to change the zoom view controls to navigation controls.

Here is my code.

Maps.java

```
public class maps extends Activity {
   static final LatLng College = new LatLng(13.1172245 , 77.6341758);

   private GoogleMap googleMap;
   float lat,lon;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mapsshow);
      try { 


            if (googleMap == null) {
               googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(College, 15));

            }

         googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(College).title("Location,click on the arrow below for directions"));


      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

}
```

I have got my api key etc, maps sucessfully loads, but i want navigation option instead of zoom view. What should i change ?

Comment: by "navigation" do you mean the current location option ?

Comment: There is a marker on a map which marks a specific location, if i click on it, it should give me the navigation option

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and it should work:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

And be sure to use use latest google map api.